# Laravel find records that exists in a CarbonPeriod

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, php-carbon

I created a CarbonPeroid object between 2 dates following this

```
$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2018-06-14', '2018-06-20');
```

Now I want to filter all those posts that exists in that $period object.

I tried like this but it doesn't work

```
        $posts = Posts::whereBetween(
            'created_at', [$period]
        )->get();
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try this? `Posts::whereBetween('created_at', ['2018-06-14', '2018-06-20'])->get();`

Comment: `whereBetween` takes an array like `[$from, $to]`.

Comment: `Posts::whereBetween('created_at', ['2018-06-14', '2018-06-20'])->get();` displays no results. I think because the date format doesn't match the format provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide start and end date from your `CarbonPeriod` object.

```
$posts = Posts::whereBetween(
        'created_at', [$period->startDate, $period->endDate]
    )->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe you want to make a `groupBy(day)` with is what habend in `CarbonPeriod`

so you can do it like this

```php
$posts = Posts::whereBetween('created_at', ['2018-06-14', '2018-06-20'])
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($val) {
        return Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('d');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2018-06-14', '2018-06-20');

//---Iterate Over the Period
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

//---Convert the period to an array of dates
$dates = $period->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign dates directly in the whereBetween method, and you dont need create date via carbonPeriod.

**Note, You most cast your dates to date format.**

Like this:

```
$posts = Posts::whereBetween(
            'created_at', [$startDate, $endDate]
        )->get();
```